# Spring's SimpleNamingContextBuilder and LDAP

Tags: java, spring, junit, ldap, spring-ldap

I'm currently trying to develop a new module for our existing web application. I'm trying to add LDAP functionality and have problems initializing the LDAP context as the SimpleNamingContextBuilder registers a context that is not working together with the [LdapTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ldap/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ldap/core/LdapTemplate.html).

In our spring `applicationContext.xml` we have several JNDI lookups, so before running a test case I have to create mock JNDI-Resources using the [SimpleNamingContextBuilder](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) in the test cases constructor.

```
SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
builder.bind("someJNDIname",someObject); //e.g. for some datasource
builder.activate();
```

In our Spring `application-context-test.xml` we have the following ldapConfiguration:

```
<bean id="ldapContextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
    <property name="url" value="ldap://ourserver:389" />
    <property name="base" value="CN=Groups,CN=ourcompany,DC=com" />
    <property name="userDn" value="CN=binduser" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>

<bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="ldapContextSource" />
</bean>
```

We run the testcase with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:application-context-test.xml"})
public class TestClass {
    public TestClass(){
       .. //init the SimpleNamingContextBuilder
    }

    @Autowired
    private LdapTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void someTestcase(){
        ldapTemplate.search("", "(objectclass=user)" ,new LdapUserMapper());
    }
 }
```

As the SimpleNamingContextBuilder is already registering a simple InitialContext I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.ldap.NotContextException: DirContext object is required.; nested exception is javax.naming.NotContextException: DirContext object is required.
  at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:198)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:319)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:259)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:571)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:556)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:411)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:431)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:451)
  at  com.somecompany.TestClass.someTestcase(TestClass.java:30)
      [...]
  at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: javax.naming.NotContextException: DirContext object is required.
  at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.castToDirContext(InitialDirContext.java:106)
  at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.getURLOrDefaultInitDirCtx(InitialDirContext.java:112)
  at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:245)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$4.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:253)
  at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:293)
  ... 35 more
```

The error tells me that the LDAP requires a `DirContext`. How can I get the SimpleNamingContextBuilder to create and use such a [DirContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/naming/directory/DirContext.html).

If I don't register the SimpleNamingContextBuilder then creating the `LDAPTemplate` will work. However I will run into other problems as other parts of the application require the JNDI lookups.

Answer (score 3):

I did not manage to get the SimpleNamingContextBuilder to create an instance of DirContext, but using a custom DirContextBuilder was the solution to get around this limitation.

The mocked SimpleNamingContext is mainly there to provide bound objects via e.g.

```
InitialContext.doLookup(String name)
```

methods - to let those ones work and provide proper support for e.g. LDAP DirContext instances, just omit the check for the "activated" context - you will bootstrap your code to apply activate() anyway, so this is no problem - at least not for the given JNDI + LDAP test case.

Missing this check, the code looks for the "**java.naming.factory.initial**" environment key and if the environment is empty (this is the case for InitialContext.doLookup(String name)) you get the mocked SimpleNamingContext with your bound objects.

If you use the LdapTemplate the environment is not empty and the key "**java.naming.factory.initial**" is set to "**com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory**" or something similar which is at least (hopefully) a DirContext.

In this case you get a working DirContext instance back from the createInitialContextFactory call and the LdapTemplate lookup is successful.

So just create a class DirContextBuilder - take the code from SimpleNamingContextBuilder - like this:

```
public class DirContextBuilder implements InitialContextFactoryBuilder {

...

public InitialContextFactory createInitialContextFactory(Hashtable<?,?> environment) {
    if (environment != null) {
...
}
```

Omit the check for **activated == null** and you are ready to test your bound JNDI objects and have a working LdapTemplate.

Comment: That doesn't solve the mixing problems. I want to initialize JNDI datasources for a database in the same context.

Comment: If you need both in the same context, this should be possible with a custom DirContextBuilder too - just create your own implementation of DirContext, or use e.g. the JBoss one (org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory).

Comment: I need both in the same context, can you show me how to do this exactly? Would really appreciate it! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. But overcome it with the below trick

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp(){
    OracleDataSource ods = null;
    try {
        ods= new OracleDataSource();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=....;
    ods.setUser(..);
    ods.setPassword(..);        

    SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = null;
    try {
        builder = SimpleNamingContextBuilder.emptyActivatedContextBuilder();
        builder.bind("some/name", ods);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Before
public void beforeTest(){
      SimpleNamingContextBuilder.getCurrentContextBuilder().deactivate();
}

@Test
public void yourTest(){
    .....
}
```

This will bind your database with some/name and also let you to connect to the ldap correctly.

Comment: I use `@BeforeClass` to register jndi before `@ContextConfiguration` configures spring context which requires the jndi for the jdbc datasource. However I need to add `builder.activate()` in order to make it work. Thanks for this trick +1 `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I researched causes and internal behaviour in `Java` and `SpringLdap` why it happens. I came to the following decision.

I customized **ContextSource** bean creation in order to solve it. This method is crutch and requires modification config that checking test mode. But it works. 
Below I present simple project demostrated it. For embeded LDAP server I used **Apache Directory Server**.

`CommonConfig.java` consisted this crutch:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question8325740.config;


import com.stackoverflow.question8325740.JndiExplorer;
import com.stackoverflow.question8325740.LdapSettings;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextSource;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.AbstractContextSource;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.NoInitialContextException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.Control;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory;
import javax.naming.spi.NamingManager;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
public class CommonConfig {

    private static class CustomLdapContextSource extends AbstractContextSource {
        @Override
        protected DirContext getDirContextInstance(Hashtable<String, Object> environment) throws NamingException {
            return new CustomLdapContext(environment, null);
        }
    }

    private static class CustomLdapContext extends InitialLdapContext {
        public CustomLdapContext() throws NamingException {
        }

        public CustomLdapContext(Hashtable<?, ?> environment, Control[] connCtls) throws NamingException {
            super(environment, connCtls);
        }

        @Override
        protected Context getDefaultInitCtx() throws NamingException {
            String className = "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory";
            InitialContextFactory factory;
            try {
                factory = (InitialContextFactory) Class.forName(className).newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                NoInitialContextException ne =
                        new NoInitialContextException(
                                "Cannot instantiate class: " + className);
                ne.setRootCause(e);
                throw ne;
            }
            return factory.getInitialContext(myProps);
        }


    }

    private static boolean checkTestMode() {
        //checking test mode using reflection in order to not collapse in real execution
        try {
            Class clazz = Class.forName("org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder");
            Object result = clazz.getMethod("getCurrentContextBuilder").invoke(null);
            return NamingManager.hasInitialContextFactoryBuilder() && result != null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }


    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public ContextSource ldapContextSource(LdapSettings ldapSettings) {
        AbstractContextSource contextSource;
        if (checkTestMode()) {
            contextSource = new CustomLdapContextSource();
        } else {
            contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        }
        contextSource.setUrl(ldapSettings.getUrl());
        contextSource.setUserDn(ldapSettings.getLogin());
        contextSource.setPassword(ldapSettings.getPassword());
        contextSource.setPooled(true);
        contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(false);

        Map<String, Object> baseEnvironmentProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        baseEnvironmentProperties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        baseEnvironmentProperties.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
        contextSource.setBaseEnvironmentProperties(baseEnvironmentProperties);
        return contextSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public LdapOperations ldapTemplate(ContextSource ldapContextSource) {
        return new LdapTemplate(ldapContextSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public JndiExplorer jndiExplorer() {
        return new JndiExplorer();
    }

}
```

`MainTest.java` using `JNDI` and `LdapOperations`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question8325740;

import com.stackoverflow.question8325740.config.CommonConfig;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.AttributesMapper;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapOperations;
import org.springframework.ldap.query.LdapQueryBuilder;
import org.springframework.ldap.test.LdapTestUtils;
import org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
import java.util.List;


@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApacheDsEmbededConfiguration.class, CommonConfig.class})
public class MainTest {
    public static final String TEST_VALUE = "testValue";


    private static SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() throws Exception {
        builder.bind(JndiExplorer.JNDI_TEST, TEST_VALUE);
        builder.activate();
        LdapTestUtils.startEmbeddedServer(ApacheDsEmbededConfiguration.PORT, ApacheDsEmbededConfiguration.DEFAULT_PARTITION_SUFFIX, "test");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void shutdown() throws Exception {
        LdapTestUtils.shutdownEmbeddedServer();
        builder.deactivate();
    }


    @Autowired
    private JndiExplorer jndiExplorer;

    @Autowired
    private LdapOperations ldapOperations;

    @Test
    public void testLdapTemplateWithSimpleJndi() {
        Assertions.assertEquals(TEST_VALUE, jndiExplorer.getValue());
        String cn = "testCN";
        String sn = "testSN";
        Attributes attrs = new BasicAttributes();
        attrs.put("objectClass", "inetOrgPerson");
        attrs.put("cn", cn);
        attrs.put("sn", sn);
        ldapOperations.bind("cn=" + cn + "," + ApacheDsEmbededConfiguration.DEFAULT_PARTITION_SUFFIX, null, attrs);

        AttributesMapper<String> mapper = new AttributesMapper<String>() {
            @Override
            public String mapFromAttributes(Attributes attributes) throws NamingException {
                return (String) attributes.get("sn").get();
            }
        };
        List<String> sns = ldapOperations.search(LdapQueryBuilder.query().base(ApacheDsEmbededConfiguration.DEFAULT_PARTITION_SUFFIX).attributes("*").where("sn").is(sn), mapper);

        Assertions.assertEquals(1, sns.size());
        String resultSn = sns.get(0);
        Assertions.assertEquals(sn, resultSn);

    }

}
```

`ApacheDsEmbededConfiguration.java`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question8325740;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ApacheDsEmbededConfiguration {

    //default password
    static final String PASSWORD = "secret";
    //default admin DN
    static final String PRINCIPAL = "uid=admin,ou=system";

    static final String DEFAULT_PARTITION_SUFFIX = "dc=stackoverflow,dc=com";
    static final int PORT = 1888;

    @Bean
    public LdapSettings ldapSettings() {
        LdapSettings settings = new LdapSettings();
        settings.setUrl("ldap://localhost:" + PORT);
        settings.setLogin(PRINCIPAL);
        settings.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        return settings;

    }

}
```

Pojo `LdapSettings.java`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question8325740;


public class LdapSettings {
    private String url;
    private String login;
    private String password;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Bean using JNDI-variable `JndiExplorer.java`:

```
package com.stackoverflow.question8325740;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

public class JndiExplorer {
    public static final String JNDI_TEST = "com/anything";

    @Resource(mappedName = JNDI_TEST)
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

And `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>question-8325740</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <junit.version>5.3.2</junit.version>
        <spring.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.ldap.version>2.3.2.RELEASE</spring.ldap.version>
        <apacheDirectoryService.version>1.5.5</apacheDirectoryService.version>
        <apacheDirectoryService.shared.version>0.9.15</apacheDirectoryService.shared.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ldap.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.ldap.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-core</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheDirectoryService.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-core-entry</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheDirectoryService.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-shared</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheDirectoryService.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheDirectoryService.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheDirectoryService.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>shared-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${apacheDirectoryService.shared.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```